# get both positive and negative correlation between features in a dict

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` of correlation between features.

```
             CRIM        ZN     INDUS      CHAS       NOX        RM       AGE  
CRIM     1.000000 -0.199458  0.404471 -0.055295  0.417521 -0.219940  0.350784   
ZN      -0.199458  1.000000 -0.533828 -0.042697 -0.516604  0.311991 -0.569537   
INDUS    0.404471 -0.533828  1.000000  0.062938  0.763651 -0.391676  0.644779   
CHAS    -0.055295 -0.042697  0.062938  1.000000  0.091203  0.091251  0.086518   
NOX      0.417521 -0.516604  0.763651  0.091203  1.000000 -0.302188  0.731470   
RM      -0.219940  0.311991 -0.391676  0.091251 -0.302188  1.000000 -0.240265   
AGE      0.350784 -0.569537  0.644779  0.086518  0.731470 -0.240265  1.000000   
DIS     -0.377904  0.664408 -0.708027 -0.099176 -0.769230  0.205246 -0.747881
```

What I want is a dictionary of `corr()` between features where value is `gt(0.5) and ne(1)` and also negative `corr()` `lt(0.5)`

I have tried

```
df.corr()[(df.corr().gt(0.5)) & (df.corr().ne(1))].stack().round(3).to_dict()
```

This gave me all positive `corr()` between features `gt(0.5)` and `ne(1)` but I also need strong negative `corr()` `le(0.5)` in the dict?

**And also are there any way to get unique values?**

In the result I need unique values. `ZN - NOX` and `NOX - ZN` should be treated as one. I'm getting both in the dict?

Comment: can you explain what you mean by unique values.? unique correlation values.?

Comment: @SreeramTP I've updated the question.

Comment: I simple trick is to loop through the dict and then take each key lets say (a,b) is the key then delete (b, a) if that exists

Comment: @SreeramTP That would do it but was looking for some other way than loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `m1` positive values and `m2` negative value masks then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) as:

```
m1 = (df.corr().gt(0.5)) & (df.corr().ne(1))
m2 = (df.corr().lt(-0.5)) & (df.corr().ne(-1))

df.corr()[m1|m2].stack().drop_duplicates().round(3).to_dict()
```

OR

```
d = df.corr()
m = ((d>0.5)&(d!=1))|((d<-0.5)&(d!=-1))
d[m].stack().drop_duplicates().round(3).to_dict()
```

---

Both produces output:

```
{('CRIM', 'ZN'): -0.199,
 ('CRIM', 'INDUS'): 0.404,
 ('CRIM', 'NOX'): 0.418,
 ('CRIM', 'RM'): -0.22,
 ('CRIM', 'AGE'): 0.351,
 ('ZN', 'INDUS'): -0.534,
 ('ZN', 'NOX'): -0.517,
 ('ZN', 'RM'): 0.312,
 ('ZN', 'AGE'): -0.57,
 ('INDUS', 'NOX'): 0.764,
 ('INDUS', 'RM'): -0.392,
 ('INDUS', 'AGE'): 0.645,
 ('NOX', 'RM'): -0.302,
 ('NOX', 'AGE'): 0.731,
 ('RM', 'AGE'): -0.24}
```

Comment: `drop_duplicates()` that was something I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @user2475 You are Welcome!.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.corr()[((df.corr().gt(0.5)) & (df.corr().ne(1))) | ((df.corr().lt(-0.5)) & (df.corr().ne(-1)))].stack().round(3).to_dict()
```

EDIT (more efficient & readable):

```
df_corr = df.corr()

high_positive_corr = (df_corr.gt(0.5)) & (df_corr.ne(1))
low_negative_corr = (df_corr.lt(-0.5)) & (df_corr.ne(-1))

df_corr[high_positive_corr | low_negative_corr].stack().round(3).to_dict()
```

so you don't compute the correlations 5 times

Comment: Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a mask with condition you need. This will be more readable.

Also, as a performance tip you can store the corr in a variable so that repeated calculation can be avoided

```
mask_1 = (df.corr().gt(0.5)) & (df.corr().ne(1))
mask_2 = (df.corr().lt(-0.5)) & (df.corr().ne(-1))

mask = mask_1 | mask_2

df.corr()[mask].stack().round(3).to_dict()
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out.